# Переключение youtube iframe с помощью Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как добиться переключения между 4 видео, так чтобы при клике на одну из них менялось главное видео?

```css
.main_video iframe{
  width:100%;
}
.video_item iframe{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.video_item{
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main_video">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_pwdixReIZ4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="video_item">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_pwdixReIZ4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
     <div class="video_item">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_pwdixReIZ4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
     <div class="video_item">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_pwdixReIZ4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант

```js
  var content;
   var maincontent;
    $('.video_item').click(function(){
     
       $(this).addClass("video_inner_new");
       maincontent = $('.main_video .video_inner').detach();
     
    
       content = $(this).find(".video_inner").detach();
        content.appendTo('.main_video');
        
             maincontent.appendTo('.video_item.video_inner_new');
     $(".video_item").removeClass("video_inner_new");
    });
```

```css
.main_video iframe{
  width:100%;
 
}
.video_item iframe{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
   pointer-events: none;
}
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.video_item{
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="main_video">
      <div class="video_inner">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_pwdixReIZ4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="video_item">
     <div class="video_inner">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xpVfcZ0ZcFM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="video_item">
      <div class="video_inner">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x8D6jzHBgAI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="video_item">
      <div class="video_inner">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_pwdixReIZ4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```